Pruning leader for second espalier level while missing a first level scaffold
I wish to espalier an advanced specimen of pear. It seemed to have one usable branch for the first level of what could be - in theory, a first horizontal cordon. It misses a branch on the opposite side.
As I understand it, to promote the growth of buds, I would need to prune the leader where I wish to see a second branch and a new leader in the next growing season. I have read that the leader will almost always take over the tree's resources and - unless pruned, the tree will not branch suitably for an espalier. The illustration shows it as option B.
Despite this information, I wonder if the tree might still push out the missing branch on the first level - opposite the existing branch - if trimmed to the second level. The illustration shows it as option A.
I marked the two options in the picture below as A and B. I am attempting to start an espalier for a modified U shape, but the cuts would probably be the same for a horizontal cordon. The reason for considering option A is to take a shortcut to start branching to the next level.
If I trim the leader to the second level - option A, will it prevent me from achieving the espalier shape on the picture?


Interesting question, I've subscribed to activity on it. Just wanted to mention you don't need to specify the reason when editing own posts. It does have advantages like helping you focus your edit on a single thing or improving post history. However the usual use case is when editing other people's posts so that it's easier to judge if your edit should be accepted or removed.
